# How do I install langid python library from github?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have attempted the following:

```
 sudo pip install git+https://github.com/saffsd/langid.py.git
```

However I get the following error.

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

However both python-dev and numpy are already installed.

```
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ dpkg -s python-numpy
Package: python-numpy
Status: install ok installed
...
```

and

```
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ dpkg -s python-dev
Package: python-dev
Status: install ok installed
...
```

Any ideas of what I could try next?

Comment: `sudo pip install langid`?

Comment: Good point.  I tried that and got the following:
selah@selah-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo pip install langid
[sudo] password for selah: 
Downloading/unpacking langid
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement langid (from versions: 1.0dev, 1.1.1dev, 1.1.2dev, 1.1.3dev, 1.1.4dev, 1.1dev)

Comment: If it is a development release, `--pre` modifier may help: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#install-pre

Comment: That got me past the "could not find a version" error.  However it gave me the same error as installing from github directly :/
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'

Answer (score 0):

Install langid's dependencies and directly the version 1.1.4 from pypy

```
sudo pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/langid/langid-1.1.4dev.tar.gz
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still gives me the same "SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'." error.